# Cuckoo report is generated in JSON file. Interpretation of json value

Tags: json, time, call, behavior, cuckoo

After the analysis is done of Malware the following sample part is generated in the JSON file.

```
{
  "calls": [
    {
      "category": "system",
      "status": 0,
      "stacktrace": [],
      "last_error": 0,
      "nt_status": -1073741515,
      "api": "LdrLoadDll",
      "return_value": 3221225781,
      "arguments": {
        "basename": "atp",
        "module_address": "0x00000000",
        "flags": 0,
        "module_name": "atp.dll",
        "stack_pivoted": 0
      },
      "time": 1584287582.774751,
      "tid": 2396,
      "flags": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

What is `"time": 1584287582.774751` in this json file?

Answer (score 1):

The time field uses the **UNIX timestamp format**, which represents the number of seconds that have passed since January 1, 1970. (UTC).
You can search for online tools, such as https://www.unixtimestamp.com/, to help you decode.

`1584287582.774751` means `Sun Mar 15 2020 15:53:02 GMT+0000`

Based on the JSON you posted, I guess the time field here refers to the time when the `LdrLoadDll` API was called.

Comment: Thank you oalieno for the clarification.